# React Recharts render blocking with a lot of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, performance, recharts

I have a use case for Recharts where I'm rendering more than 20,000 data points, which results in a blocking render:

[image: See on CodeSandbox]

*(The CodeSandbox has a small pulse animation, so it's easier to see the blocking render when creating new chart data.)*

When measuring the performance with dev tools, it is clear that the cause for this is not the browser's `painting` or `rendering` activity, but Recharts' `scripting` activity:

[image: performance]

By no means do I want to blame Recharts here, 20k points is a lot, but does anyone know if there's a way around the blocking render?

**Things I tried:**

1.) Incremental loading

Incrementally load more data (e.g. 2k + 2k + 2k + ... = 20k), which just results in more, smaller render blocking moments.

2.) Loading animation before rendering

Added a small boolean state in the rendering component to track the "mounted" status, which will at least show a loading animation when the chart component mounts, so the user is not waiting on a blank page/route switch:

```
const [showLoading, setShowLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
const { isLoading, data } = useXY()   // remote data fetching
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsMounted(true);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  setShowLoading(isLoading || !isMounted);
}, [isLoading, isMounted]);

...

if (showLoading) return <LoadingAnimation />

return <div>...chart...</div>
```

---

**Code of the chart:**
*(see CodeSandbox for full code)*

```tsx
function Chart({ data }: { data: Data }) {
  console.log("⌛ Rendering chart");

  const lineData = useMemo(() => {
    return data.lines;
  }, [data.lines]);

  const areaData = useMemo(() => {
    return data.areas;
  }, [data.areas]);

  return (
    <ComposedChart
      width={500}
      height={400}
      margin={{
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid stroke="#f5f5f5" />
      <XAxis dataKey="ts" type="number" />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      {areaData.map((area) => (
        <Area
          // @ts-ignore
          data={area.data}
          dataKey="value"
          isAnimationActive={false}
          key={area.id}
          type="monotone"
          fill="#8884d8"
          stroke="#8884d8"
        />
      ))}
      {lineData.map((line) => (
        <Line
          data={line.data}
          dataKey="value"
          isAnimationActive={false}
          key={line.id}
          type="monotone"
          stroke="#ff7300"
        />
      ))}
    </ComposedChart>
  );
}
```

Comment: hi, i'm currently in a similar situation as you where i have to plot a dataset with ~4000+ values, how did you go about implementing the loading spinner until the chart has completely rendered all the datapoints? i'm not sure how to hooking into the lifecycle states of these Rechart components

Answer (score 4):

You can use (the currently experimental) React [Concurrent Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html).
In concurrent mode, rendering is none blocking.

```
export default function App() {
  // imagine data coming from an async request
  const [data, setData] = useState<Data>(() => createData());
  const [startTransition, isPending] = unstable_useTransition();
  function handleNoneBlockingClick() {
    startTransition(() => setData(createData()));
  }
  function handleBlockingClick() {
    setData(createData());
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleNoneBlockingClick}>
        (None blocking) Regenerate data
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleBlockingClick}>(Blocking) Regenerate data</button>
      {isPending && <div>...pending</div>}
      {data && (
        <>
          <p>
            Number of data points to render:{" "}
            {useMemo(
              () =>
                data.lines.reduce((acc, item) => {
                  return acc + item.data.length;
                }, 0),
              [data.lines]
            ) +
              useMemo(
                () =>
                  data.areas.reduce((acc, item) => {
                    return acc + item.data.length;
                  }, 0),
                [data.areas]
              )}
          </p>
          <Animation />
          <Chart data={data} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this example, I'm using the new unstable_useTransition hook, and startTransition whenever the button is clicked, for a none blocking calculation of the chart data.

The animation is not in perfect 60fps, but the site is still responsive!

See the differences in this fork of your code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/concurrent-mode-recharts-render-blocking-forked-m62kf?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I'm aware of concurrent mode and this is a great example. Unfortunately I can't use unstable APIs for my software at the moment, but thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bennett Dams Let's hope it comes out soon! You can never know with them... I'll try to think of a more stable answer. Note that there are some optimizations in my answer that help a bit with render times even without concurrent mode. Like using memo on the data.map inside of render.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Also, what's the difference between the inline memo and a memo outside of the render?

Comment: @Bennett Dams It doesn't matter at all that useMemo it is inline or stored in a variable. Actually the whole function component is a big render step. The optimisation I did was to memoize the mapping from data to the react components array. So the take away is that it is very much possible to also memoize calculating JSX tags with useMemo, for very long inputs.